# LIE on commit from Hibernate Search

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

We're adding Hibernate Search 3.4 to our existing web application (using Hibernate 3.6 and Spring 3.2.3). With the default

```
<prop key="hibernate.search.lucene_version">LUCENE_31</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">C:\scratch\lucene</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.Rules.directory_provider">ram</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.search.indexing_strategy">event</prop>
```

we're getting quite a few LIEs on commiting transactions. The stacktrace will be something like:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion); nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:690)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:794)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:665)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:475)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:270)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy153.save(Unknown Source)
    at net.umbrella.ui.controller.VendorController.save(VendorController.java:210)
    at net.umbrella.ui.controller.VendorController.updateExistingObject(VendorController.java:150)
    at net.umbrella.ui.controller.VendorController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f6a74d75.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at net.umbrella.ui.controller.VendorController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3afa98fc.updateExistingObject(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at net.umbrella.mvc.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:88)
    at net.umbrella.mvc.UmbrellaRequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(UmbrellaRequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at net.umbrella.mvc.UmbrellaRequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(UmbrellaRequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.umbrella.context.HttpRequestPreprocessFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestPreprocessFilter.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.umbrella.context.UserExperienceAndSessionCleanupFilter.doFilterInternal(UserExperienceAndSessionCleanupFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at net.umbrella.services.security.SwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:328)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at net.umbrella.services.security.ChangePasswordFilter.doFilterInternal(ChangePasswordFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.beforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:138)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:657)
     ... 84 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.search.util.HibernateHelper.unproxy(HibernateHelper.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.HibernateStatelessInitializer.unproxy(HibernateStatelessInitializer.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.unproxy(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:603)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFields(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.getDocument(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.createAddWork(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.addWorkToQueue(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.WorkPlan$PerEntityWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.enqueueLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.search.engine.WorkPlan.getPlannedLuceneWork(WorkPlan.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(WorkQueue.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:172)
     ... 90 more
```

The VendorController will save a vendor object which was previously loaded using a preload pattern. The classes look like this:

```
@Indexed
public class VendorModel {
  @DocumentId
  protected int id;
  @ContainedIn
  protected Set<CreditorPaymentModel> payments = new HashSet<CreditorPaymentModel>(0);
  ..
}

@Indexed
public class CreditorPaymentModel {
  @DocumentId
  private int id;
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private BranchModel branch;
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private VendorModel paymentpartner;
  ..
}

@Indexed
public class BranchModel {
  @DocumentId
  protected int id;
  ..
}
```

The preload will load the vendor, along with the payment collection. Within the payment collection, the branch is NOT preloaded. On save (ie. on the commit transaction boundary), we observe that Hibernate Search runs into an LIE when trying to unproxy the payment.branch.

In case of an "event" indexing strategy, does the entire object tree (document builder tree) need to be properly loaded? Or, in other words, do we need to preload objects for the sole purpose of Hibernate Search being able to build a document to pass to the indexer? Are there other approaches?

(We explicitly do NOT want to use an OpenSessionInView solution)

Thanks
Simon

Comment: I had this problem, I made all indexed associations Eager and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In case of an "event" indexing strategy, does the entire object tree
>   (document builder tree) need to be properly loaded? Or, in other
>   words, do we need to preload objects for the sole purpose of Hibernate
>   Search being able to build a document to pass to the indexer? Are
>   there other approaches?

At the time the Lucene Document gets built, Hibernate Search must be able to access the state of all the entities which needs to be indexed. Either the data is eagerly loaded or if lazy loaded Search must be able to un-proxy it. In the latter case Search needs the Session which loaded the entity in the first place.

> We explicitly do NOT want to use an OpenSessionInView solution

Personally I think this is the easiest solution. Any reason why you are opting against it. However, if you really don't want to use this pattern, you need to either load the data all the time eagerly or you could consider using fetch profiles. In the later case you will need to make sure that the right fetch profile is executed whenever indexing occurs.

Comment: I was hoping (and expecting) the Hibernate Search would be able to re-attach objects not bound to the current session. We'll go ahead and implement a saveOrUpdateListener which traces the HS annotations and loads whatever is necessary. I dislike the OSIV because it won't let you control what gets written to the model entities. That design creates the risk of an unwanted data flush on an object on which data changes should have stayed transient. But, thanks for your clarification.